# Meteor local package, phaser game, asset loading?

Tags: meteor, phaser-framework

Ok I'm trying to make a package from a Phaser game, been researching this for a couple of days, but it doesn't seem to work.
I think I identified the problem though, hopefully somebody can help me with this!

I set everything up to make use of a local package, which all works.
Untill I'm preloading an asset.

This is my Menu class

```
Menu = function() {
    console.log(this);
}

Menu.prototype = {
    preload: function(){
        this.load.image('background', 'assets/background.png');
        console.log("ok in preload");
    },
    create: function(){
        this.background = this.game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'background');
        console.log("ok in create");
        var text = "We're getting there";
        var style = { font: "23px Arial", fill: "#ff0044", align: "center" };

        var t = game.add.text(game.world.centerX, 0, text, style);
    },
};
```

and I call this by doing

```
game = new Phaser.Game(400, 300, Phaser.AUTO, "gameWindow");
game.state.add('menu', Menu);
game.state.start('menu');
```

which all seems to work by looking at the console logs, as long as I don't try to load the image in the preload function, if I do it just keeps stuck in the preload function.

The background.png is located at my root folder going 'public/assets/background.png'.
So I'm thinking when I try to access this from a local package, it is having trouble getting there...

my package.js is this btw:

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "game one"
});

Package.on_use(function (api, where) {
    api.use(['phaserio'], 'client');

    api.add_files(['states/menu.js'],
                  ['client']);

    api.export('Menu', ['client']);
});
```

Anybody out there, that sees what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to load public images from the app, but it depends when that preload sequence is running. Packages get parsed first. So is your new game created within a `Meteor.startUp ->`? by which time the app itself is initialized?

Also you can put assets in the package itself.
are you using 0.9? there are some issues with paths for static assets inside packages
see this thread:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2602

for 0.9 packages you'll have to add a bit more info

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "phaser for meteor",
  version: '0.0.1',
  git: 'https://github.com/dcsan/package-dev',
  name: "YOURNAME:phaser"
});
```

currently if you use something like replacing colon with an underscore:

```
/packages/YOURNAME_phaser/added/path/to/asset.png
```

if you get phaser wrapped i would also be interested, so please publish it to atmosphere!